# iOS UINavigationBar Style issues

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, unwind-segue

I have an issue with UINavigationBar styling:

1) I have applied style change in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
    //Change Navigation bar appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor (red: 231.0/255.0, green: 95.0/255.0, blue: 53.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    if let barFont = UIFont (name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold", size: 22.0){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: barFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]   
    }

    //Status bar text change to white
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    //Toolbar Buttons color change
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 235.0/255.0, green: 73.0/255.0, blue: 27.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 237.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 243.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

2) I launch the app and go from main view to the connected one using push segue in the same navigation controller (this issue won't appear if I use modal segue) and unwind to the first view

3) Navigation Bar loses the title and styling, status bar also loses changed style. Though if I change it (style and title) once again in ViewWillAppear - it works fine.

The question is: should this work like that and one has to reload styling in every ViewWillAppear or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Michael

Comment: No, setting the UIAppearance proxies once should work for the entire app. If you want different styling on a particular view you can simply customize the properties (not using appearance) in each case, but UIAppearance essentially sets default values app-wide. There's likely something else going on here, although I unfortunately can't speak to what that might be given the current information.

Comment: Actually, you should be right: I have some elements that only have their appearance changed in Storyboard. And that might be the case - will check out! But what about navigation title that accidentally disappears? Did you face something like that?

Comment: I haven't. I typically set the titles of my view controllers in their viewDidLoad.